# Handling Cross Thread Exception in Vb.Net Forms

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, user-controls

I have a windows form on to which i have declared custom controls ( label, panels text boxes), The issue is I am loading images of that control in local thread , but some of the pictures not not downloading from web stream, hence the exception, Now i am setting image property Nothing in **Catch** block, and trying to set other UI panels properties, but it throws exception,

**Exception :**

> "Cross thread operation not valid: Control "XXXXXXXXXX" accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created. "

kindly somebody tell the simplest way to set the property in case of exception occur so I may set the properties of other controls.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you don't touch controls in methods executed on a secondary thread.  Only touch controls on the UI thread.  Where you might usually just do this:

```
myPictureBox.Image = myImage
```

you now write a method like this:

```
Private Sub SetPictureBoxImage(img As Image)
    If myPictureBox.InvokeRequired Then
        myPictureBox.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of Image)(AddressOf SetPictureBoxImage), img)
    Else
        myPictureBox.Image = img
    End If
End Sub
```

and then call it on the secondary thread instead of setting the Image property directly:

```
SetPictureBoxImage(myImage)
```

Note that that method will succeed whether it's called on the UI thread or a secondary thread so you can call it whether you know that you're on a secondary thread or not.

[Check this out](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?498387-Accessing-Controls-from-Worker-Threads&highlight=) for more information.

**EDIT**

```
Private Sub UpdateUI(img As Image, visible As Boolean)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of Image, Boolean)(AddressOf UpdateUI), img, visible)
    Else
        myPictureBox.Image = img
        myPanel.Visible = visible
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that I used the InvokeRequired and Invoke members of the form instead of a specific control.  It actually doesn't matter which form or control those are members of as long as they are owned by the same UI thread but to me it seems logical to use the same control your updating if there's only one or else use the form.

Note also that the signature of the delegate changes to match the signature of the method so that they have the same number and type of parameters.

Comment: Ok, fine, but I have to set Visible to two of panels as well, what should I do for that?, can you give me a hint?

Comment: @DareDevil - Put everything you need to be done on the GUI thread in the `Else` part of the method (it's probably wise to rename the method to `UpdatePanels` or `UpdateView` ) That's it.

Comment: You can make as many changes to as many controls as you like in the one method.  If you need to make a bunch of updates to the UI at the same time then you should put them all in the same method.  If you need to do the updates at different times then you use separate methods.  For instance, you could write another method `SetPanelVisible` that did basically the same thing but with the Visible property of a Panel control instead of the Image property of a PictureBox control.  If you want to do it all together then put it together in one method.  I've added a further code example of that above.

Comment: Give me time to write it! >:(

Comment: Let me try myself Buddy

Comment: Or, as I've seen detailed elsewhere on SO (and the route I took), make Control extension methods, eg `lblMessage.ThreadSafeText("Updated text for the UI label control");` which call the `Invoke` pattern above. (This also makes a pretty good case for extension _Properties_ in .NET, I think: `lblMessage.ThreadSafeText = "Updated text for ..."`. One can dream ...)

Comment: @SteveCinq, I'm not sure that that's really worthwhile because, if you know enough to create an extension method, you probably know enough to just use `lblMessage.Invoke(Sub() lblMesage.Text = someText)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have done that UI change in this function:**MethodInvoker**

```
Try
  'Code that was throwing exception here 
Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() 
        'All UI changes made here
        End Sub))
End Try
```

Comment: That's a bad option.  Using exceptions to control the flow of execution is always bad.  If you test `InvokeRequired` before making the call - as you're supposed to - then you know that you need to call `Invoke` without an exception being thrown.  You should always avoid an exception being thrown if it is reasonable to do so.  They should only occur in actually exceptional circumstances and, if you know that you will be accessing controls from secondary threads, there's nothing exceptional about doing so.

Answer (score -1):

```
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

Will allow you to change your TextBox,Label and etc... in execution

Comment: That will prevent this specific exception being thrown but that doesn't mean that it's safe to do so. Cross-thread operations are not allowed by default because some will fail and it's not easy to know which those will be, so it is safest not do any.